# Where is the gnome-power-manager binary in 12.04?

Tags: suspend, battery, gnome-power-manager

Using a tiling window manager, I called `gnome-power-manager` in earlier Ubuntu versions to get the battery tray icon.

In 12.04, the `gnome-power-manager` package is still there, but the binary is gone.

What is the 12.04 equivalent that starts the applet?

Answer (score 1):

In the standard installation with Unity you have the same facilities but gnome-power-manager is not running. I believe the facilities are provided by indicator-power.
The indicator-x things are threaded into gnome much deeper than gnome-power-manager was.
In case you need something with the same functionality you can try xfce4-power-manager
It is a little bit slow to "dock" in the tray, but works well and reminds me of the old power-manager. It is light and will not bring all xfce4 with it, but juts a couple of libraries.

I hope it helps
                 Herna